# Trying up saleor application by using Docker. Trouble with elasticsearch connection

Tags: elasticsearch, saleor

Trying up an application by using Docker. When I run

```
docker-compose run web python3 manage.py populatedb --createsuperuser
```

I receive:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   ConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused) caused by:
>   NewConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to increase amount of mmap memory.Found here: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using saleor [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) from github that is because 
the `elasticsearch` container wouldn't start with this configuration and that is because of:

```
mem_limit: 512m
```

**Removing** `mem_limit` solved the problem in my case. What you can try though is to:

- set this limit to a **higher level**
- lower `Xms / Xmx` JAVA_OPTS like:

  ```
  ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true
  ```

**UPDATE:**

Also try upgrading to `elasticsearch:6.5.2`. See https://github.com/avoinea/docker.deploy.saleor

Comment: I have changed  search container to such view: 
  search:
    image: elasticsearch:6.4.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - saleor-backend-tier
    volumes:
      - ./saleor-search:/usr/share/elasticsearch/
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
 
    mem_limit: 2048m
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true "

but doesn't have changed. I still have connection error with elasticksearch.
Also I tried remove mem_limit, but doesn't changed

Comment: I also upgraded to `elasticsearch:6.5.2`. See https://github.com/avoinea/docker.deploy.saleor

Comment: I also seem to be facing this same issue. Its driving me mad!

Comment: @doogan , did you manage to resolve your problem? appreciate some advice..